# Cannot find the next div attribute id

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to find the next element of the id,can you please suggest to find the next element of the id.

I am having the html code:

```
<div class="togg_child" style="font-size: 17px; margin: 5px;">
<a id="cats_1" class="test" href="javascript:">Diamond</a>
<div id="subctg_1" class="test1"></div>
</div>
```

I am using this Jquery Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.test').click( function(){
        var tid = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(tid);
        $("#"+tid).parent().next('div').attr('id');
        alert(id1);die;

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the parent():

```
$("#"+tid).next('div').attr('id');
```

Or simply do this:

```
$(this).next('div').attr('id');
```

This will get subctg_1 id.

And don't use die it is available in php not in js.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `$(this)` reference inside the click handler to target the clicked anchor instead of constructing a new id selector, Constructing a new id selector of the current element seems unnecessary.

```
$('.test').click( function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).next('div').attr('id'));
});
```

`.parent()` would select the element's parent, but here our requirement is to select the immediately next sibling, so just invoke `.next('div')` to the current element

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HEe3Q/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` for current element and remove parent() in your scenario

```
$(this).next('div').attr('id');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HEe3Q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  $("#"+tid).parent().next('div').attr('id');

        with

  $("#"+tid).next().attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

      $('.test').click( function(){

            alert($(this).siblings().attr("id"));

      });
});
```

in the siblings you can pass any selector. Example, `.siblings("div")`